# wordpress widget don't call the css

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I created a custom widget but it don't work how it should do cause don't take the css style call.
I added the css to the header but not in the widget.I must include it in the widget too?
if yes, how i could do?

this is the wp version 
[image]

and this is how it shoul be

[image]

this is the code.....

```
    //Widget view
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
    ?>

    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 ..........
```

Comment: is there any live url? so that we can inspect through

Comment: Show the code you use to load the CSS

Comment: i uploaded the code....i tried with enqueue script too but nothing...Must i use the register_style directly in widget?